# Why activator command is so slow

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

This is the first time I install activator and start to play with Play 2.

After download the Activator from https://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.5/typesafe-activator-1.3.5-minimal.zip, I followed the guide try to setup my first play app.

However, everything I run an activator command, like activator ui, activator new  , or activator run inside the app directory, the command will stuck there for 5-10 minutes, sometimes even longer, before it starts to download dependencies.

```
$ activator run
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.8 ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/jars/sbt.jar ...
```

At first, I thought it is because of my network (I'm in China). So I logged into a server on AWS and it is same result.

Is there something I forgot to setup or this is what it is with activator command?

I'm running Scala 2.11.7 with Java 1.8.0_51-b16 on a Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.4.

Comment: I am experiencing the same.

Comment: Anyone resolved this? I still get this with activator ui etc just takes for ever.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you guys by any chance use Homebrew to install Activator?

Answer (score 1):

add offline:=true in build.sbt , it might help

or some time if any wrong configuration in application.conf , it might be taking good amount of time trying to figure out that ,so your running becomes very slow

Answer (score 0):

Well depending on your connection it just might take a while - keep in mind that the current version of the Typesafe Activator is about *650 MB*. Although 10 minutes is really not normal.

Keep in mind that you can also download the *offline* version - including all dependencies ready to go: https://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.9/typesafe-activator-1.3.9.zip